# Why does JQuery ':not' selector still hide all the elements?

Tags: jquery

I am using this to hide all but first child:

```
$('cite:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

Yet, it just hides everything. Has anyone experienced the same?

Live example on [this page](http://johnpett.com/goodwinhartshorn/fold-flat-grater-plus/).

Comment: Are any of the `cite` elements the real `: first-child` of the parent elements? Post sample/ representative code *here* in your question, don't expect us to follow links around the internet to help diagnose your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('cite:not(:first-child)').hide();` take the first-child element, but the actual first `cite` is the second child (there is a `p` right before). Try this :

```
$('cite:not(:first)').hide();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was always of the opinion that 'first-child' was the first instance of the selector, not the children of the parent! Now I know!

Comment: You're thinking of `:first-of-type`.